# Trying to build the mapbox render example app with OSMesa and getting a error

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to build the render example app in `mapbox-gl-native` with OSMesa, but when I run the app I get the following errors.

```
./mbgl-render --debug -s https://osm.tegola.io/maps/osm/style.json
[INFO] {mbgl-render}[General]: GPU Identifier: Mesa OffScreen
[ERROR] {mbgl-render}[Setup]: loading style failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?): error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
Error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?): error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
mbgl-render: ../../../platform/default/thread_local.cpp:36: mbgl::util::ThreadLocal<T>::~ThreadLocal() [with T = mbgl::Scheduler]: Assertion `!get()' failed.
Aborted
```

I don't know what I need to do to get rid of the assertion failure?

I'm building using `make WITH_OSMESA=ON render`
I'm building on ubuntu:18.04 docker image.

Don't know if this helps:

git hash is 153acd981b344d7a3963514cfb3241e8cb27ba2d .

Running the mbgl-test app fails the following tests:

```
[==========] 706 tests from 96 test cases ran. (155451 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 703 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 3 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] Annotations.DebugSparse
[  FAILED  ] CustomGeometrySource.Grid
[  FAILED  ] Timer.Basic

 3 FAILED TESTS
  YOU HAVE 2 DISABLED TESTS
```